# How can I put multiple conditions in a React component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, conditional-statements

In React I can conditionally render any div like:

```
{hasContent &&
   <span>{value}</span>
}
```

I'm trying to put in two conditions like this:

```
{hasContent || hasDesc &&
   <span>{value}</span>
}
```

but it doesn't work.

I want to render the `span` if there is `hasContent` or `hasDesc`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

It's just operator precedence: `&&` takes priority over `||`. Just use parentheses to get it processed the way you want:

```
{(hasContent || hasDesc) &&
   <span>{value}</span>
}
```